# how to insert data from a sensor in specific position in array using python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I need to insert data in a specific position of an array, The data come from a sensor and it comes in this format `{temp,xpos,ypos}`. so I need to populate the array with the data in that position.
it must work like this

```
   data = {25,2,2}
   arr = [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.] [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
   process....
   print(arr)
   >>[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.] [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][0. 0. 25. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I know that it can be possible, passing the position where the data come from in data list.

```
data = np.array([8, 1, 1, 9, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 8, 2, 2, 9, 3, 3, 8, 2, 2])

V = np.zeros((6, 6))

V[1][2] = data[0]
V[1][1] = data[3]
V[1][5] = data[6]
V[3][2] = data[9]
V[4][2] = data[12]
V[5][2] = data[15]

print(V)
```

but this is not what I want, BTW. This only works properly when i pass the data like this `V[1][2]= data[3]`. When I try to do this `V[data[1]][data[2]]=data[3]` the output is an error. I don't know how to do it, i hope you can help me

Comment: `data = {25,2,2}` makes it a set, so actually data would be just {25, 2} (only 2 elements). you should get data as list `data = [25,2,2]` and then access data[1], data[2].

Comment: Thanks, yes i was declaring it bad. but i was accessing to the data, in a bas way

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a comma. See if this helps:

```
data = [25, 2, 2]
V = np.zeros((6, 6))
V[data[1], data[2]] = data[0]
print(V)
```